# Constructing a Homothety

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

This exercise has me stumped.  I am meant to apply concepts concerning homotheties with circles to solve it.  The problem states:

Given halflines *k*, *l* starting at a common point (let's call this point *V*), and a point *P* inside the angle formed by *k* and *l*, construct a circle through *P* tangent to *k* and *l*.

I tried multiple approaches to constructing this circle however I have yet to solve the problem.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Aren't you satisfied with my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following figure:

[image]

Here are the steps of construction you have to follow:

1. Construct the angle bisector of $k$ and $l$
2. Take an arbitrary point (red thick) on the angle bisector.
3. Drop a perpendicular to $l$ from the red point.
4. Draw the red circle.
5. Draw a line through $P$ and the intersection of $k$ and $l$.
6. This line will intersect the red circle.
7. Connect this latter intersection point with the center of the red circle.
8. Draw a parallel with this latter line through $P$.
9. This parallel will intersect the angle bisector of $k$ and $l$.
10. This intersection point will be the center of the circle wanted.

Note that there is another circle through P that is tangent to $k$ and $l$. We could have chosen the other intersection point on the red circle...

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and step-by-step solution, very helpful!